# NGINX cmd command does not work

Tags: windows, apache, nginx

When i use my mac, i installed by brew. And it made all command usable every where

But, chocolatey does not allow windows to install NGINX.

So i downloaded under the C: and unzipped it.

Unlike Mac, i can't use NGINX or NGINX -s reload.

I think the 'bin' folder should be located in window 'PATH', but i could not know where it is.

When i order 'NGINX', cmd returns NGINX is not internal or external command.

How can i use these commands? Even though, Windows' directory tree is not similar with Mac's

Comment: is the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html) any help to you?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm sorry that i did not read it. prefix command 'start' resolve the problem. thank you for caring me

Comment: taskkill /f  /IM nginx.exe <--- for windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download the nginx binary package from nginx website,when you unpacked it,there was no `bin` folder in it.The executable application is nginx.exe.The following is what looks like if you use `ls` command in the nginx directory.

```
C:\nginx-1.8.1>ls -1
conf
contrib
docs
html
logs
nginx.exe
temp
```

Comment: the command `dir` does similar work without the need to install anything :D